# Should I publicize the Earth Science Stack Exchange site in my geology apps?

Tags: discussion, support

[I am asking in Earth Science Meta if they want that I include an ad in the geology apps I am programming for first courses students.](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1983/is-it-a-good-idea-to-publicite-the-site-in-my-geology-apps-for-first-courses-stu)

I don't know how to do Data Explorer queries, but my perception is the *[Earth Science](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/tour)* Stack Exchange site was much more active around 2015, and I want to help the site with more geology questions and more geologists answering.

The problem is I might fill the forum with geology questions, while geology is only one of the branches of Earth Sciences.

I am not receiving answers, so could I make the decision unilaterally? Or can other users of Stack Exchange discuss it?

Could I use the logo of the site in the ad?

Comment: Feel free to link to the site from anywhere, but **do not use its logo**, it's trademarked by Stack Exchange and you should contact them first if you want to use it in your own products.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one [post about Community ADs](https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com/q/66/6593), in general, and the Stack Exchange format; though you can do things differently on your own website.

The Earth Sciences site users have discussed their community ad and have come up with an image.

The link should go to here: https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/ and you can use this image:

[image: image of Earth with Earth Science on Stack Exchange written above]

They discussed this on their meta in [2015](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1455/15154).

The site logo is the property of Stack Exchange, so don't use it.

Comment: @Universal_learner That image is licensed under CC BY SA, so you already have permission to use it (with attribution).

Comment: @Laurel info about the author to quote him in the footprint?

Comment: @Universal_learner It's [from this answer](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1524). Preferred attribution is post link, username and user profile link. (Like all SE content.)

Comment: @Laurel, thank you for fielding questions during my absence.